# counting digits in an integer from textbox except "0"

Tags: c#, input, integer

I have 2 textboxes where a first textbox is an object and the 2nd textbox is a result textbox. What I need to do is to count the digits of first textbox's input without 0 in the 2nd textbox.
For example, if a user inputs the value 100 OR 101 OR 001 then the result should be shown for 100 = Counted 1 (00 should not be counted), 101 = counted 2(0 should not be counted), 001 = counted 1(00 should not be counted).

I have used this code line to count the digits from the first textbox:

```
int Counted = Textbox1.Text.Length;
Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Counted).ToString();
```

Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int result = Textbox1.Text.Count(c => char.IsDigit(c) && c != '0');
Textbox2.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Nice, It's working for me. I've another question related to this. I've a comboBox named days. In the comboBox I've added a list of days like 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, 4 days and so on. I wanted to get only numeric numbers from that combobox's selected value and want to bind in a variable. Is that possible? If you know please help me.

Comment: "cannot convert from 'string' to 'char' ". I've used this method but this error is coming up. Actually, I am new to c# therefore I don't know this error.

Comment: Your Answere is the best, so I am accepting this as answere.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a Label when you have to print a result.

Then, you have to convert your int to string :

```
 string res = Textbox1.Text.Replace("0", ""); 
 int count = res.Length; 
 Label1.Text = count.ToString();
```

Comment: Tim's solution is far more elegant. This involves: parsing a string to an `int`, converting that `int` to a `string`, creating a new string without the 0 digits, and then counting the length.

Comment: Yes, he answered a bit faster than me ^^, but I let this answer up if people are in need (like that, there are 2 solutions)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
if(textBox.Text.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x) == false))
{
    throw new Exception("You must use only digits as value");
}

textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Count(x => x != '0').ToString();
```

You can write it this way too:

```
textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Count(x => char.IsDigit(x) ? x != '0' : throw new Exception("You must use as value only digits")).ToString();
```